# AJAX Submit with no redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to have some data send to submit.php. The data does submit but it redirects me to the submit.php page. How can I submit this with out changing page?

JS

```
function submitq() {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("submitdata").value=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST",submit.php,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: How is the function called.

Comment: There's no code here that performs a redirect.  What else is on the page that could cause it?

Comment: Why not use the JQuery library? It handles browser differences for you, and the final markup is cleaner. Not trying to be rude, just a question.

Comment: It's called from a <button onclick="submitq()"> @adeneo

Comment: @David - I would guess a form, why else would the page redirect, but whithout knowing how the function is called, or what the form looks like, it's hard to tell where to place the `return false;`

Comment: @BillyJMcDonald I tried jQuery, but I didn't really like it's AJAX functions

Comment: Then set the buttons type `<button type="button" onclick="submitq()">` and that will stop the form from submitting

Comment: And note that you have syntax errors, the filename in xmlhttp.open needs to be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out.

The form can't have an action of a method because that will redirect it after it is posted.

Comment: Removing those will still reload the page, it just won't redirect, and using ajax to send the data is useless if you intend to submit the form anyway